# crear una objeto de resumen de un arreglo

Tags: javascript

Busco la manera de crear un objeto que contenga un resumen con todos los parametros existentes en cada item del arreglo. 
ejemplo tel arreglo:

```
const peopleArray = [
  { id: 123, name: "dave", age: 23 , ar: [{id:1},2,3]},
  { id: 456, name: "chris", age: 23 },
  { id: 789, name: "bob", age: 23 },
  { id: 123, name: "dave", age: 23 , ar: [{ir:1},2,3]},

]
```

salida

```
     { "age": 23,
       "id": 102,
       "name":"chris" 
       "tim",
       "ar": [{
              "id": 1,
              "ir": 1
              },
              2,3
             ]
    }
```

lo importante para mi es poder obtener todos los key en el mismo nivel que fue encontrado, utilice la funcion array.reduce, pero no obtengo todos los parametros.

para que busco hacer esto? 
tengo un arreglo con 100 item, cada item tiene ciertos parametros los que deseo sumar , entonces quiero hacer 1 objeto que tenga todos los key y el total de cada uno.

Comment: El objeto que escribiste como slaida no es un json valido

Comment: @Sacha lo habia escrito como un objeto

Comment: No entiendo muy bien la formulación de tu pregunta, lo que quieres es obtener un objeto json? la salida es lo que tu esperas?

Comment: lo que busco es hacer como un merge pero de todos los item de un arreglo, busco poder sumar todos los item numericos y hacer un objeto con los resultados

Answer (score 0):

Creo que no te has explicado muy bien. En el primer código que parece JS, como te han dicho en comentarios, no tienes bien formado el JSON, ya que todas las keys de un objeto JSON deben estar entre comillas.

Además, cada uno de los elementos del array (los objetos JSON), deberían ir entre comillas, y el ultimo elemento del array no va seguido de una coma.
La cadena de JSON debería quedar así:

```
const peopleArray = [
  "{ 'id': 123, 'name': 'dave', 'age': 23 , 'ar': [{'id':1},2,3]}",
  "{ 'id': 456, 'name': 'chris', 'age': 23 }",
  "{ 'id': 789, 'name': 'bob', 'age': 23 }",
  "{ 'id': 123, 'name': 'dave', 'age': 23 , 'ar': [{'ir':1},2,3]}"
]
```

Si quieres obtener los items del array y parsearlos a objetos, necesitaríamos saber cual es el lenguaje con el cual vas a parsearlo: PHP, Java, Javascript...

Lo que parece que quieres es obtener cada uno de los items del array e imprimirlos no?. No tiene mucho misterio de primeras (aunque luego veo que mezclas objetos del array de la propiedad 'ar' en la salida, lo que no tiene mucho sentido). Si parseas cada uno de los Strings del array a un objeto JSON y lo imprimes deberías tener el resultado que buscas. 
Te dejo un enlace donde se puede aprender lo básico de JSON en Javascript.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp